# Unable to display login username in Hydra

Tags: ssh, password-cracking, hydra, telnet

So I'm performing an authentication cracking lab using Hydra, I use the following command;

`hydra -L /usr/share/ncrack/minimal.usr -P /usr/share/wordlists/s1.txt -f -V 192.168.99.22 telnet`

The command used seems to give me the intended result, however, it doesn't display the actual username. The output is somewhat like this

`[23][telnet] host: 192.168.99.22   login: *# minimal list of very common usernames*    password: *thepassword*`

How do I make it display the actual login username?

The weird thing is, if I use the same command for SSH, it gives me the proper username and password combination. Something like this

`[22][ssh] host: 192.168.99.22   login: root   password: *thepassword*`

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Check your **/usr/share/ncrack/minimal.usr** file...

Remove the line **# minimal list of very common username** from the file; otherwise, Hydra will not work as expected.